# How to initialize values for nested struct array in golang

Tags: go

My struct

```
type Result struct {
   name   string
   Objects []struct {
       id int
   }
}
```

Initialize values for this

```
func main() {
   var r Result;
   r.name  = "Vanaraj";
   r.Objects[0].id = 10;
   fmt.Println(r)
}
```

I got this error. "panic: runtime error: index out of range"

How to fix this?

Answer (score 29):

Firstly, I'd say it's more idiomatic to define a type for your struct, regardless of how simple the struct is. For example:

```golang
type MyStruct struct {
    MyField int
}
```

This would mean changing your `Result` struct to be as follows:

```golang
type Result struct {
    name   string
    Objects []MyStruct
}
```

The reason your program panics is because you're trying to access an area in memory (an item in your `Object`s array) that hasn't been allocated yet.

For arrays of structs, this needs to be done with `make`.

```golang
r.Objects = make([]MyStruct, 0)
```

Then, in order to add to your array safely, you're better off instantiating an individual `MyStruct`, i.e.

```golang
ms := MyStruct{
    MyField: 10,
}
```

And then `append`ing this to your `r.Objects` array

```golang
r.Objects = append(r.Objects, ms)
```

For more information about `make`, see [the docs](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#allocation_make)

Comment: length must be specified in make, isn't it? `make([]MyStruct, 0)`

Comment: Is there a way without refactoring the code to initialize the array of Objects

Comment: @Katiyman if you mean that you want to initialise a list of, say, 10 Objects, I think you could use `r.Objects = make([]MyStruct, 10)`.

Answer (score 26):

After defining the struct as suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33892965/309683):

```
type MyStruct struct {
    MyField int
}


type Result struct {
    Name   string
    Objects []MyStruct
}
```

Then you can initialize a `Result` object like this:

```
result := Result{
    Name: "I am Groot",
    Objects: []MyStruct{
        {
            MyField: 1,
        },
        {
            MyField: 2,
        },
        {
            MyField: 3,
        },
    },
}
```

Full code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    result := Result{
        Name: "I am Groot",
        Objects: []MyStruct{
            {
                MyField: 1,
            },
            {
                MyField: 2,
            },
            {
                MyField: 3,
            },
        },
    }

    fmt.Println(result)

}

type MyStruct struct {
    MyField int
}

type Result struct {
    Name    string
    Objects []MyStruct
}
```

You can verify this in this [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/k8h3Ga3b1V9).

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to initialize the array Objects in using make: `Objects: make([]MyStruct, 0, 10)` in order to say initialize it to a slice?

Answer (score 6):

`Objects` contains no elements. You need to `append` element first. Like this:

```
r.Objects = append(r.Objects, struct{ id int }{})
```

Also you can omit `r.Objects[0].id = 10;` using initialization of your struct like this:

```
r.Objects = append(r.Objects, struct{ id int }{ 10 })
```

Comment: Thanks Ronindev. type Result struct {
    name   string
    Objects []struct {
        id int
        name string
        email string
    }
} How to add values for this?

Comment: RobinDev, How to add multiple variable in append?

Comment: @vanarajcs something like this `r.Objects = append(r.Objects, struct{ id int }{10}, struct{ id int }{20})`

Comment: It's better to use named type for your `struct{ id int }`, as @matt-schofield suggested

Comment: r.Objects = append(r.Objects, struct{ id int, string name}{ 10 "Vanaraj"}) is it right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96028/discussion-between-ronindev-and-vanarajcs).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a dumb idea, but you can roundtrip it through JSON:

```
package main

import (
   "bytes"
   "encoding/json"
)

type (
   a []interface{}
   m map[string]interface{}
)

func decode(in, out interface{}) {
   var b bytes.Buffer
   json.NewEncoder(&b).Encode(in)
   json.NewDecoder(&b).Decode(out)
}
```

Example:

```
package main
import "fmt"

type result struct {
   Name string
   Objects []struct {
      Id int
   }
}

func main() {
   r := m{
      "Name": "Vanaraj",
      "Objects": a{
         m{"Id": 10},
      },
   }
   var s result
   decode(r, &s)
   fmt.Printf("%+v\n", s) // {Name:Vanaraj Objects:[{Id:10}]}
}
```