# How to access a slice in struct in golang

Tags: arrays, go, struct, field

How can I access a slice defined inside the struct?

```
type Car struct {
    Year int
    Name string
    Type []int
}
```

//Accessing "Type" array field as below causes error: array out of range.

```
Car.Type[0] = 12
Car.Type[1] = 15
Car.Type[2] = 11
```

Comment: Did you make sure to initialize the array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize values for nested struct array in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892599/how-to-initialize-values-for-nested-struct-array-in-golang)

Comment: I think this is what you want: Car.Type = []int{12,15,11}

Comment: Take the Tour of Go which explains slices in detail.

Comment: You are using a slice and not a array. I would also recomend the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) these things are explained there.

Answer (score 4):

You mistake `slice` for `array`. It must be:

```
type Car struct {
    Year int
    Name string
    Type [3]int // <---
}
```

See [running code](https://play.golang.org/p/iCMgV1oYT-2)

You should read this tour: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/6

Comment: You only very, very rarely need to use an array in golang. You use a slice, but OP needs to initialise it before using it

Answer (score 4):

You can't directly access a slice field if it's not been initialised. You're defining a struct to have 3 fields: `Year` of type int, this is a simple value that is part of the struct. Same goes for `Name`. The `Type` field, however, is a slice. A slice is a *reference type*. That means it's essentially a hidden struct (called the slice header) with underlying pointer to an array that is allocated dynamically for you. This underlying pointer is, at the time you initialise your variable, `nil`.

```
type Car struct {
    Year int
    Name string
    Type []int
}
```

Can be seen as:

```
type Car struct {
    Year int
    Name string
    Type struct{
        type: "int",
        array *[]T
    }
}
```

Not exactly, but you get the idea. When you write:

```
c := Car{}
```

All you've allocated is the int, string and the slice *header*. You must, therefore initialise the slice first:

```
c := Car{
    Year: 2018,
    Name: "vroom",
    Type: []int{
        1, 2, 3,
    },
}
```

There are many ways to initialise the slice, of course. You don't have to set the values just yet, but you could, for example, allocate and initialise the memory you need in one go:

```
c.Type = make([]int, 3) // allocates an initialised 3 elements in the slice to 0
```

you can also allocate but not initialise the slice by specifying the capacity (this is useful to avoid reallocating and moving the slice around too often):

```
c.Type = make([]int, 0, 3)
```

Alternatively, you can have the runtime do it all for you, using append:

```
c.Type = append(c.Type, 1, 2, 3)
```

### Some examples [here](https://play.golang.org/p/hP1_YDpRiQd)

---

A bit more background. Slices and maps work similarly, broadly speaking. Because they are reference types, that rely on pointers internally, it's possible for functions that have a slice as a return type to return `nil` for example. This doesn't work for functions returning an `int`:

```
func nilSlice() []int {
    return nil
}
```

Because the return type is a slice, what this function will return is, essentially, an empty slice. Accessing it will result in the same error you occurred: index out of range.

Trying to return nil from a function like this won't even compile:

```
func nilInt() int {
    nil
}
```

The resulting error will say something like *"Can't use nil as type int"*. Treat slices as pointer types: they need to be safely initialised before use. Always check their length, and if you need to optimise, look at how the builtin `append` function is implemented. It'll just exponentially grow the capacity of the underlying array. Something that you may not always want. It's trivial to optimise this sort of stuff

Comment: Thanks Elias for detail explanation. I used append() to initialize Type field and it fixed my issue.

Comment: @leo888 No worries, please upvote/accept this answer if it helped. That's the correct way to mark the question as answered

Comment: this is the correct answer. Very detailed explanation, thanks!

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem is the `c.Type := make(...` in the examples correct? I think it should be `c.Type = make(...`

Comment: @JuanJoséRamírez: well spotted, made the edit. Thanks for saying this is the correct answer, can't believe someone saying to use an array gets +3 on a golang question. A language where you're being told time and again to use slices instead of arrays in most cases.

Answer (score -1):

You are confusing Slices and Array. Slices are like dynamic arrays. The way you have defined the slice, their index is not defined until they are appended. For the above code:

```
type Car struct {
Type []int
}
var car Car
car.Type = append(car.Type, 12)
car.Type = append(car.Type, 15)
car.Type = append(car.Type, 11)
```

Also, *Car* in your case is a *type* of object not a object itself. I have declared object *car* of type *Car*.

Comment: `They have not defined index until they are appended.` is not true. Slices point to underlying array. you are confusing with nil slices.

Comment: Yeah! I was saying with respect to the way he has defined his slice. Edited and corrected it.

Comment: @Himanshu: If the slice field of the struct wasn't initialised, the OP is trying to set values on a nil slice. Also `append` is variadic, so no reason to call it three times, just `car.Type = append(car.Type, 12, 15, 11)` will do

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem yes I know it is variadic  function but this is not my answer and the answer is wrong.

Comment: @Himanshu: I know it's not your answer, and the answer isn't 100%, hence I provided my quite verbose answer, because the current highest scoring one is advising to use an array instead of a slice, which is also wrong (as slices and arrays are not the same thing)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem what you want from me friend. Create a chat room. If you have any thing to discuss.

Comment: @Himanshu steady on... wasn't trying to argue. Just trying to dot the I's and cross the T's. No need to get all defensive

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I am not arguing. I am supporting your reasons. you are correct.